# Memory issues [Node.js server]

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, pouchdb

So I'm running on a 1GB aws instance and I'm finding I have memory issues. But really I shouldn't, the largest set of data it deals with is about 50MB. Looking at my stack trace my code is struggling to parse a large object. Just before it crashed it was trying to use pouchdb to add one of my 50MB data objects to a local db (pouchdb is nosql). Also concurrently during the crash another dataset was being replicated up to my couchdb server. I figured my GC should keep my memory usage low enough that this wouldn't be an issue.

I'm pretty new to these kinds of issues, I'd appreciate some advice. The server was running with node allocated 800MB of memory in this particular instance. Thanks guys

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PouchDBs compaction was causing the issue, so I swapped over to autocompact. Frustrating anyway, wish I had a better way of fixing this.